# sketch a graph with given properties of $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus

Sketch a graph with given properties:

$(i)\quad$ Continuous everywhere except for where a vertical asymptote at $x=0$

$(ii)\quad$$ f'(x)<0$ for $-\infty <x<0$

$(iii)\quad$ $f'(x)>0$ for $0<x<\infty$

$(iv)\quad$ $f''(x)<0$ for $-\infty<x<0$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'(x)$ is negative in the interval $(-\infty,0)$, you know that $f(x)$ is decreasing in this interval. Likewise, since $f'(x)$ is positive in the interval $(0,\infty)$, $f(x)$ needs to increase.

Since $f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=o$, the value of $f(x)$ increases approaching $|infty$ or $-infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$. This is represented by a sharp increase or decrease near $0$.

Because $f''(x)<0$ in the interval $(-\infty,0)$, $f(x)$ should be decreasing at an increasing rate.

Using these hints should help you create a graph.

Comment: You mean $f$ decreases at a *decreasing* rate?

Answer (score 0):

From the given conditions, the curve should look something like that of $$y=\log|x|,$$ or $$-\frac{1}{x^2}.$$